# Publish downloaded tms tiles using GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, tile-map-service

I downloaded a set of tms files from a mapping software, in .png format, with a "tms.xml" file.
I want to use GeoServer to publish this data as a wms service.
Is it achievable?
How to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to add them using the image pyramid extension.